# Property names with spaces in object literals

Tags: javascript, object

I'm just wondering, with the "one", "two", "three" stuff, could there be a space? So instead of "one" it could be "one meow"?

```
var meow    = { one:        function (t) { return "a"; },
                two:        function (t) { return "b"; },
                three:      function (t) { return "c"; }
              };
```

Comment: See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 11):

Sure, there can be spaces in property names, but then you have to enclose them in `"`:

```
var meow    = {
            "one meow": function (t) { return "a"; },
            two:        function (t) { return "b"; },
            three:      function (t) { return "c"; }
            };
```

When you want to access that property later, use the bracket syntax:

```
console.log( meow["one meow"]() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you can no longer access the property as `meow.one mewo`, instead you need to use the bracket syntax: `meow['one mewo']`.

Similarly, when you define the object, you need to quote the keys:

```
var meow = {
  'one meow'  : function (t) { return "a"; },
  two         : function (t) { return "b"; },
  'three meow': function (t) { return "c"; }
};
```