# Run Javascript Function with Spaces in Function name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am novice in Javascript and i want to test a website using JavaScript. My Javascript file has two function **Login** and **Some Function**

Here, **Some Function** has space in between and i want to call this function via npm run command.

File **somefile.js**

```
module.exports = {
    "Login": function (browser) {
        console.log("Hi --> Pawan");
    },
    "Some Function": function (browser) {
        console.log("Some Script data");
    }
};
```

File **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sampletest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "somefile.js",
  "scripts": {
     "loginScript": "node -e \"require('./someFile').Login()\"",
     "somefuncScript": "node -e \"require('./someFile').\"Some Function()\"\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Commands used are :-

**npm run loginScript** returns Hi --> Pawan

**npm run somefuncScript** returns **BLANK**

Comment: Please confirm me again how it is duplicate? i am not calling function from js file but from json file. Please remove duplicate marking. @CertainPerformance

Comment: You're trying to use `require('./someFile')."Some Function()"`, but that syntax isn't valid - see the canonical to see how to use spaces when looking up property names

Comment: I have already tried with %20 in between and even unicode character U+0020 in between but that didn't worked

Comment: See the linked question - this has nothing to do with URL encoding

Comment: Please remove duplicate mark and let some professional to answer it for me. Thanks, link was not helpful for my understanding

Comment: Look at the first example in the top answer in the linked question - it shows how to look up properties which can't be accessed with dot notation

Comment: I resolved it not using your link but a different link. This works now fine with "somefuncScript": "node -e \"require('./someFile')['Some Function']()\"" 

Please remove duplicate so that other dont face same issue, i want to answer this

Comment: That looks to be exactly the solution described in the top answer in the linked question - putting the quoted property inside of brackets

Comment: Nope that is not the answer but solved using below one. Yours Duplicate marking is similar one which hints to possible solution but not exact answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724158/property-names-with-spaces-in-object-literals